# How to pass neo4j Nodes from one database to another

Tags: java, neo4j

I have two separate Database for Neo4j nodes. How can i pass Nodes from one database to another??

LIKE

```
  1. Machine1 - GraphDB1- (Nodes-Students)

  2.Machine2 - GraphDB2- (Nodes-Books)
```

so how can i pass book nodes to GraphDB1.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't do that, you would create all your data in *one* database.

In general you can query one databases with [Cypher](http://neo4j.org/tracks/cypher) and then create / insert the data in the second database.

On the first database, return a node and relationship-list:

```
start n=node(*)
match n-[r]->()
return n,r
```

Us a programming language to create a CSV file or a set of cypher `CREATE` statements from those results. For importing CSV see: http://neo4j.org/develop/import esp. the "spreadsheet method" and/or the CSV batch-importer.

Enable auto-indexing in your second server: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/auto-indexing.html

Cypher Create statements for nodes and relationships look like this:

```
CREATE ({name:"Foo", age: 12});
CREATE ({name:"Bar", age: 18});

START n=node:node_auto_index(name="Foo"),
      m=node:node_auto_index(name="Bar")
CREATE n-[:KNOWS {since:2012}]->m;
```

You can also check out my Neo4j-Import tools for the Neo4j-Shell: https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-shell-tools

Comment: can you please provide some example or any idea or reference to this?? " query one databases with Cypher and then create / insert the data in the second database."